# My Adsense is 403 Forbidden

Tags: adsense

I have currently added Google Adsense on my website. My Website is made by a blogger with a custom domain http://www.dukaweb.net/. This is the first time I add Google Adsense on this website but I got the 403 Forbidden

Help me please, sorry for my bad English
 [image]

Answer (score 2):

Your domain listed in black list. Its mean your have already applied too many times for your domain in pass and they reject it. Or you are using hosted account Adsense on your custom domain. Rarely your domain listed  under policy violation list.

Answer (score 0):

in my experience, i've placed popcash and another ads on my site before google adsense review, even i removed it and my site was approved by adsense, i must request google to review my site on google webmaster tools.

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/abusive-experience

[image]